# How to extract mail atachment with PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, email

I'm extracting emails from a database where they're stored as strings.  I need to parse these emails to extract their attachments.  I guess there must already be some library to do this easily but I can't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PEAR::Mail::mimeDecode](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode) should do what you're looking for

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a MailParse extension that is a lot faster then using the PEAR alternative which is native PHP.

Here is a library that wraps this extension:

http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/

Example:

```
// require mime parser library
require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');

// instantiate the mime parser
$Parser = new MimeMailParser();

// set the email text for parsing
$Parser->setText($text);

// get attachments
$attachments = $Parser->getAttachments();
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using the Zend_Mail component of the Zend Framework

Maybe this example, which can also be found in the documentation helps:

```
// get the first none multipart part
$part = $message;
while ($part->isMultipart()) {
    $part = $message->getPart(1);
}
echo 'Type of this part is ' . strtok($part->contentType, ';') . "\n";
echo "Content:\n";
echo $part->getContent();
```

I don't know however how you can tell Zend Mail to read from strings, maybe there's some work required to do this, but then you'd have a full-fletched library that does what you want and some more(like reading the subject, etc.).

**Edit**:

I just had a second look at it and realized that all you have to do is write an own storage implementation(subclass Zend_Mail_Storage_Abstract) which shouldn't be so hard to do.

I think that's the cleanest solution you'll get, albeit a little effort is required to make it work.

If you're looking for a more quick'n'dirty kind of solution someone else might be able to help you.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

PhpMimeParser - parse multipart mime message(attachments, inline images, base64, quoted-printable) https://github.com/breakermind/PhpMimeParser You can cut mime messages from files, string.

```
// Load .eml mime message from file
$str = file_get_contents('mime-mixed-related-alternative.eml');

// Format output
echo "<pre>";

// Create object MimeParser
$m = new PhpMimeParser($str);

// Show Emails
print_r($m->mTo);
print_r($m->mFrom);
print_r($m->mBcc);
print_r($m->mCc);

// Show Message
echo $m->mSubject;
echo $m->mHtml;
echo $m->mText;
print_r($m->mInlineList);

// Show Files
print_r($m->mFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

E-mail attachments are MIME encoded and added to the message body using headers. The PEAR  MIME decode package will do what you need:
http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mimeDecode

Answer (score 0):

There's a better library out there:
https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser

It is installable via Composer.

Since this has the same name as the one on Google Code that was linked to elsewhere in this SO post, I think it's the successor to it, but I can't tell. The authorship info is harder to find on Google Code, so I cannot confirm it's the same author.

Some sample code (from the project README):

```
// Include the library first
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$path = 'path/to/mail.txt';
$Parser = new PhpMimeMailParser\Parser();

$Parser->setStream(fopen($path, "r"));

//  Loop through all the Attachments
if (count($attachments) > 0) {
  foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    echo 'Filename : '.$attachment->getFilename().'<br />'; // logo.jpg
    echo 'Filesize : '.filesize($attach_dir.$attachment->getFilename()).'<br />'; // 1000
    echo 'Filetype : '.$attachment->getContentType().'<br />'; // image/jpeg
    echo 'MIME part string : '.$attachment->getMimePartStr().'<br />'; // (the whole MIME part of the attachment)
  }
}
```