# Reading POST data in PHP from cUrl

Tags: php, curl, http-post

I am using cUrl in PHP to request from some external service.

Interesting enough, the server is responding with raw "multipart/form-data" instead of binary file data.

My website is using a shared hosting, therefore PECL HTTP is not an option.

Is there a way to parse this data with PHP?

Sample code:

```
$response = curl_exec($cUrl);

/* $response is raw "multipart/form-data" string

   --MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_DDF2A2C71485B8C94C135176149950475371
   Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

   (xml data goes here)

   --MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_DDF2A2C71485B8C94C135176149950475371
   Content-Type: application/zip
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

   (binary file data goes here)

*/
```

EDIT: I tried piping the response to a localhost HTTP request, but the respond data is likely to exceed the allowed memory size in PHP process. Expending mem limit is not very practical, this action also dramatically reduces the server performance dramatically.

If there is no alternatives to the original question, you may suggest a way to handle very large POST requests, along with XML parsing, in terms of *streams* in PHP.

I know this would be hard, please comment. I am open for discussions.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a MIME mail parsing library. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238642/how-to-extract-mail-atachment-with-php/1240048#1240048

Comment: This is a pure `form-data` and does not contain mail headers, but I will give it a try. I see this very close to a solution before actually trying.

Comment: Rated up for the comment as the bounty will end before the Lunar New Year ends, that before I have a chance to get the code at office.

Comment: The only sensible way to do this is to pipe the data through a local request to another PHP script. Performance is going to suck if you parse the data in PHP. If you read and dispatch the incoming data in chunks, memory usage shouldn't be too high.

Comment: @Andrew I'm afraid that will be too many codes, just strip it down to a intelligible question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need the zip file from the response I guess you could just write a tmp file to save the curl response to, and stream that as a workaround:
Never tried that with multipart curls, but I guess it should work.

```
$fh = fopen('/tmp/foo', 'w'); 
$cUrl = curl_init('http://example.com/foo'); 
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh); // redirect output to filehandle
curl_exec($cUrl); 
curl_close($cUrl);
fclose($fh); // close filehandle or the file will be corrupted
```

if you do NOT need anything but the xml part of the response you might want to disable headers

```
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
```

and add option to only accept xml as a response

```
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));
//That's a workaround since there is no available curl option to do so but http allows that
```

## [EDIT]

A Shot in the dark...
can you test with these curlopt settings to see if modifiying these help anything

```
$headers = array (
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: ' . $compatLevel,  // API version
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $devID,
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ' . $appID,
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ' . $certID,
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: ' . $verb,
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: ' . $siteID, 
    );

$cUrl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_URL, $serverUrl);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0 );
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ebatns;xmlstyle;1.0' );
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 1 );      // HTTP version must be 1.0
$response = curl_exec($cUrl);

if ( !$response ) {
    print "curl error " . curl_errno($cUrl ) . PHP_EOL;
}
curl_close($cUrl);
```

## [EDIT II]

This is just a try, as mentioned I cannot get my curled pages to respond with a multipart form data. So be gentle with me here ;)

```
$content_type = ""; //use last know content-type as a trigger
$tmp_cnt_file = "tmp/tmpfile";
$xml_response = ""; // this will hold the "usable" curl response
$hidx = 0; //header index.. counting the number of different headers received

function read_header($cUrl, $string)// this will be called once for every line of each header received
{ 
    global $content_type, $hidx;
    $length = strlen($string);
    if (preg_match('/Content-Type:(.*)/', $string, $match))
    {
        $content_type = $match[1];
        $hidx++;
    }
    /* 
    should set  $content_type to 'application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"' for the first 
    and to 'application/zip' for the second response body   

    echo "Header: $string<br />\n";
    */
    return $length;
}

function read_body($cUrl, $string)
{
    global $content_header, $xml_response, $tmp_cnt_file, $hidx;
    $length = strlen($string);
    if(stripos ( $content_type , "xml") !== false)
        $xml_response .= $string;
    elseif(stripos ($content_type, "zip") !== false)
    {
        $handle = fopen($tmp_cnt_file."-".$hidx.".zip", "a");
        fwrite($handle, $string);
        fclose($handle);
    }
    /*
    elseif {...} else{...}
    depending on your needs

    echo "Received $length bytes<br />\n";
    */
    return $length;
}
```

and of course set the proper curlopts

```
// Set callback function for header
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'read_header');
// Set callback function for body
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'read_body');
```

don't forget to NOT save the curl response to a variable because of the memory issues,
hopefully all you need will be in the $xml_response above anyways.

```
//$response = curl_exec($cUrl);
curl_exec($cUrl);
```

And for parsing your code you can refer to `$xml_response` and the temp files you created starting with `tmp/tmpfile-2` in this scenario. Again, I have not been able to test the code above in any way. So this might not work (but it should imho ;))

## [EDIT III]

Say we want curl to write all incoming data directly to another (outgoing) stream, in this case a socket connection

I'm not sure if it is as easy as this:

```
$fs = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);
$cUrl = curl_init('http://example.com/foo'); 
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fs); // redirect output to sockethandle
curl_exec($cUrl); 
curl_close($cUrl);
fclose($fs); // close handle
```

else we will have to use our known write and header functions with just a little trick

```
//first open the socket (before initiating curl)
$fs = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);
// now for the new callback function
function socket_pipe($cUrl, $string)
{ 
    global $fs;
    $length = strlen($string);
    fputs($fs, $string); // add NOTHING to the received line just send it to $fs; that was easy wasn't it?
    return $length;
}
// and of course for the CURLOPT part
// Set callback function for header
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'socket_pipe');
// Set the same callback function for body
curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'socket_pipe');

// do not forget to 
fclose($fs); //when we're done
```

The thing is, not editing the result and simply piping it to `$fs` will make it necessary that apache is listening on a certain port which you then assign your script to.
Or you will need to add ONE header line directly after `fsockopen`

```
fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.0\n"); //where path is your script of course
```

Comment: What I got from the first curl request is in the format of `multipart/form-data` which is rarely used in response, sending it as a file will directly put the form data inside `$_FILES` in the next request and PHP will do nothing in parsing the payload.

Comment: so `$_FILES` and `$_POST` is stored in the same file, oakay. But still it should prevent exceeding the php memory limit when you parse said file instead of the curl response when opening the file again with fopen and parse it from the file handler. You might want to read header & body sizes from the response and store it in a variable so that you can easily skip to the correct offset of the response-file. If I find the time today I'll post a complete example.

Comment: Okay.. this IS strange, I tried hard to get a `multipart/form-data` back from a curl request but I can't. Not even if I curl the upload-form.html instead of the upload.php that the form action points to. I'm sorry would you mind letting me know your `CURLOPT_URL` url to achieve this?

Comment: Not very practical to make a quick test, as I was working with the ebay api which requires a bit of setup before it works.

Comment: true since I don't even have any valid ebay api-key... as a shot in the dark I edited my answer above (due to the code-length). Maybe we can at least trace the origin of your problem

Comment: This make sense, but the memory limit thing will may need something like `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` to properly pipe it. While the curl callbacks does not support actually writing to a request, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: the thing is, allthough you trigger a writefunction `$response` will also contain the full response as before (well.. at least it was in all of my tests) so it won't help reducing the memory load, that's why I suggested to write it to the filesystem first, but on a multipart response like your's it should be triggered twice I assume...I need to think about this. I'll be back ;)

Comment: I added some write and header functions for you to test & play around with; I'm sorry for not being able to test them myself properly.

Comment: I get what you mean, but then how do I stream the temp file outward as the new request content? I see no such a "write" callback in libcurl itself, not to mention the PHP binding ...

Comment: If that is really the case, despite this is already how far I have gone myself, I will accept your answer because it is the platform's problem.

Comment: well to stream the tempfile outwards would require a new curl with `$requestBody = array("file" => "@".realpath($tmpfile)....);` , maybe `curl_multi_init`would come in handy here, but I've never been in a situation like this.. so maybe there is a better solution that we both just don't know of *shrug*

Comment: The `@` thing is just having curl POST as if it is a simple file upload, and in the suggested way it will escape the original `multipart/form-data` and wrap it with another one, under the parameter name `file` as the code provided.

Comment: yes, isn't that what you were asking for? _...but then how do I stream the temp file outward as the new request content?_ or do you want to manipulate the **current** request content? That's not possible. Or do you intent to stream **all** including headers, xml and file as a request to another url (using curl as a proxy) then maybe you could `fsockopen` a connection and  try to `curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_FILE, $socketconnetion);` if I'm correct that should `fputs` all incoming lines directly into the socketconnection, if not buffer the result and socketwrite when curl is done.

Comment: I guess it is about sending the response as the raw content of another request, having apache to parse the payload. Wrapping it again as a file upload does nothing to the first response I got, it will only appears as-is in `$_FILES` of the second request.

Comment: All writing callbacks in PHP is about incoming **response** of the first request. The ideal thing we need here is somewhere to write/steam to the outgoing **request** of the second request.

Comment: If you do not split the response and `fputs` it to a socketconnection it will act as an ordinary request, it will not add any new header information nor wrap any content, it's just a socketconnection... I'll explain above (code and such..)

Comment: Didn't think it this way, I was relying on higher level libs too much. This is almost, if not already, solved the situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry i can't help much because you did not put much code but i remember i was having a similar issue when i was playing with curl_setopt options.

Did you use **CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER**?

From php documentation -> **CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER**-> TRUE to return the raw output when CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is used.

Comment: The case is that I got the response in raw multipart/form-data format, which usually only used for requests. I don't want it to be raw, but some kind of parsing mechanism apache and PHP does before things get into my code instead.

Answer (score 0):

just set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER CURLOPT_POST

```
        $c = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                    array());
        $rst_str = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-assemble you Binary data doing something like this, I hope it helps.

```
$file_array = explode("\n\r", $file, 2);
$header_array = explode("\n", $file_array[0]);
foreach($header_array as $header_value) {
  $header_pieces = explode(':', $header_value);
  if(count($header_pieces) == 2) {
    $headers[$header_pieces[0]] = trim($header_pieces[1]);
  }
}
header('Content-type: ' . $headers['Content-Type']);
header('Content-Disposition: ' . $headers['Content-Disposition']);
echo substr($file_array[1], 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need binary data, have you tried below?

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```